# Delphi and CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA vs. FOLDERID_LocalAppData

Tags: windows, delphi

I'm using Delphi XE2 on Win7 x64, compiling for Win32.

I've started using `CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA` to design installations for my first software release.

I see on MSDN that as of Vista, MS wants us to start using [`KNOWNFOLDERID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457.aspx) values instead of [`CSIDL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494.aspx) values:

However, when I try to replace `GetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA,false)` with `GetSpecialFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData,false)`, XE2 won't recognize `FOLDERID_LocalAppData`.

I would think that since XE2 came out long after Vista, that there *should* (if you'll forgive me) be support/recognition of these constants (?) in `Winapi.Windows` in XE2.

If not, does anyone know if Win10 still recognizes `CSIDL` values?

Comment: Delphi doesn't implement the entire Windows API. You can either define them yourself, or use the Jedi library which does wrap the entire WinAPI.

Comment: GetSpecialFolderPath nicely wraps SHGetKnownFolderPath anyway from Vista onwards, so job done without you doing anything!

Comment: Microsoft is not in the habit of getting rid of old APIs, so yes, Win10 still supports `CSIDL`, even though `KNOWNFOLDERID` is preferred (and in some cases is required, as newer folders do not have `CSIDL`s defined).

Comment: Thanks for all the help on my first visit. I first joined "Programmers" by mistake, and that post (which) I now need to delete, auto-updated, so my apologies for not replying until I hit refresh here: deep into JwaWindows.pas...

Answer (score 4):

Not everything in the Win32 API that Delphi natively supports is implemented in the `Winapi.Windows` unit.  For instance, `CSIDL` support is implemented in the `Winapi.SHFolder` unit, and `KNOWNFOLDERID` support (which yes, does exist in XE2) is implemented in the `Winapi.KnownFolders` unit.

`GetSpecialFolderPath()` is not a native Delphi function, so you must be using third-party code.  `CSIDL` is an `Integer` that is passed to [`SHGetFolderPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx) (or older `CSIDL`-based functions), whereas `KNOWNFOLDERID` is a `TGuid` that is passed to [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) instead.  So you can't just pass a `FOLDERID_...` constant to `GetSpecialFolderPath()` unless it has been overloaded to accept either a `CSIDL` or `KNOWNFOLDERID` as input.

Comment: Yes, I wrote (copied) my own function. Remy, thanks for the big clue about needing a new function with a TGuid parameter, and for Winapi.KnownFolders.pas: I've avoided "learning" the Jedi culture for decades (I'm not easily "acculturated"), even though I know it is valuable for many. If I can make it with XE2 "only," that's a big help.

Comment: I see that you edited my post: more to learn. Is there a help section that explains how to encode the formatting which you applied?

Comment: See the [Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) documentation.  Also, when you are editing a post, there is the `?` in the top-right corner of the editor that gives you links to markdown syntax.

Comment: More thanks. I've studied here for sometime, and I can begin to see and appreciate the evolution of the culture of technical discourse here, and I can appreciate the work invested, because our 'net cultures (and all human discourse) have needed all of the help we can get. Is there another section or group as part of this system which focuses on the general culture and language needs addressed by this "Stack" institution?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you are asking for, but have you looked at the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) sections yet?

Comment: "Tour," I did automatically, and it seems I was immediately rewarded with one of the re-wards. "Help" could probably benefit me greatly, and "Meta" is not something I might have thought of or encountered. I'll check it out. After posting my previous comment/request to you, I was thinking that it might be interesting to have participated in or read along with any of the discussion which helped to form this unique culture. "Programmers" seems to offer some of that history or philosophy. Discussion along that general direction is what I think I was imagining.

Comment: Stack Overflow blog has curation of history

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, are you referring to this site, that this "Stack Overflow" is referred to as the "Stack Overflow blog"? I haven't been able to find a separate blog, so I'm asking to clarify, since I'm new to SO. (and I'm not sure with all of the variations of web design/structure if there is a canonical definition of "blog.")

Comment: Are you joking here? Search for stackoverflow blog.

Comment: David, no joke. There's just so much I don't know, and web culture seems infinite, and I hardly ever followed blogs. Perhaps its people like me who have allowed such as "Politico.com" to take over the much of the U.S. mindset (I get this from books, not blogs). But yes, after writing my question to you, it occurred to me that I should have just asked [Google] about stackoverflow blog...apologies...learning.